# Laravel 5.1 Redirecting a Logged in User to Another Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

We have two different applications on Laravel framework, We want to redirect the logged-in user from one application to the other, when they click a link, without having to logged in again, on the other application.

Can someone guide/suggest something to make it working please?

Comment: You should use SSO (Single Sing On) for this

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi  something more simpler than SSO?

Comment: Maybe with session/local storage?

Comment: @MaxTaylor with session, I think, not possible. we can store user credentials on session but how we are going to send it to the other application?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is how, we get around the solution

**Application A**
1. we store the logged in user user id and password (hashed password) in session.
2. Create a link with that user id and password
3. When Logged in User click that link, post user id and password to Application B

**on Application B**
1. Create a new post route with 2 Parameters (User id and password)
2. In Controller function, Match the user submitted user id and hashed password with the user ID and Password in application B database.
3. If it is exactly same, Logged in user with

```
Auth::loginUsingId($UserID, true);
```

and redirect him/her to Logged in area, otherwise redirect him/her to Login Page.

Hope this helps some other person looking for the same.